# ruby hash with database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, hash

I am trying to understand this line of code:

```
@rating = Rating.where(review_id: @review.id, user_id: @current_user.id).first
```

The line of code comes from a Ruby on Rails app that has a user, review, and rating model. Here is what I understand so far:

- @rating is a variable
- Rating.where().first is a method
- review_id: @review.id + user_id: @current_user.id are parameters- and are an implicit hash key/value pair

How does `review_id: @review.id` or `user_id: @current_user.id` work with the database?

**Update question:** Sorry I'm still confused. How does `@review.id` or `@current_user.id` point to anything in the database? I have nothing in my database starting with the @ symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 fields: `"review_id"`, `"user_id"` in table `"ratings"`.

Symbol @ - means that is instance variable and it is available not only in the controller

variable structure example:

```
@current_user = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Jhon",
  last_name: "Wayne"
}
```

this means that `@current_user.id = 1`

```
user_id: @current_user.id
```

And query search 1 in table `ratings` field `user_id`

Answer (score 0):

This line selects all the ratings which belong to a review with id `@review.id` and belong to the currently logged-in user with id `@current_user.id`.

The SQL version of this will look something like this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE review_id = #{@review.id} AND user_id = #{@current_user.id}"
```

**EDIT**: In the hash, every key refers to the column name in the table and the corresponding value is what you are searching for in that column. That value is given by what is stored in the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know database SQL queries then

```
Rating.where(review_id: @review.id, user_id: @current_user.id)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * from ratings where review_id = @review.id AND user_id = @current_user.id;
```

1. @rating is not just a variable , its a instance variable
2. Rating.where() will return an array of ratings. and Rating.where().first will return first record of the array

Answer (score 0):

`Rating.where` provides `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which knows about conditions on `review_id` and `user_id`. When you call `first` for the object -- it executes sql query, and appends `LIMIT 1` condition.

```
SELECT ratings.* FROM ratings WHERE ratings.review_id = 11 AND ratings.user_id = 12 LIMIT 1
```

The `ORM` converts the response from the database to the ruby object. Which you place in the instance variable `@rating`, probably in a controller. This variable will be accessible in the view.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a hash in where clause it means then key of hash is field name and value of that key is value in database